# Using the correct wildcard on Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word, wildcards

I'm completely new to wildcards and stuff but I really need to refine my search results for a project.

Here is a picture:

[image: LINK TO THE PICTURE]

First of all, I have codes like this:

```
1PinfraestruturaT3
1PparaP3
```

I want to find all the results of `1P` and `T` (with anything in the middle).

But when I use the code `1P*T` it finds results like the picture on the left. However, I just want to find results like the picture on the right (just the sequence in the same line it starts). 
How can do I so?

Comment: `1P[a-z]{1,100}T`